# Phoenix - No current connection - HRegion.mutateRowsWithLocks : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I try to run Phoenix in localhost and can't resolve the error (can't find where is mutateRowsWithLocks). I would like a lot to run SQL queries on HBase so hope someone will help me:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException:    
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: 
SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.mutateRowsWithLocks(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Collection;)V
.....
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.mutateRowsWithLocks(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Collection;)V
```

By running "!list", I have

```
1 active connection:
#0  closed jdbc:phoenix:localhost
```

By running "create table test (field bigint);" I have:

```
No current connection
```

I have copied in hbase/lib the jars phoenix-server, and I also try with the 
phoenix-core jar. (re-run HBase of course)

My environment is 
Hadoop 2.6
hbase 0.98.10
Phoenix 4.3.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked !

Thank you to "Andrew P" from Phoenix:
"
You will need to upgrade to HBase 0.98.10.1 to resolve this issue. Or, you can recompile Phoenix from source with -Dhbase.version=0.98.10 (or 0.98.10.1)
"